# Вывод значений переменной или неправильная функция в python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, beautiful-soup

Не могу разобраться с выводом результатов работы элементарного парсера на python 3. Хочу вывести список всех ссылок с определенной таблицы веб страницы, но получаю только первую ссылку из списка.
Предполагаю, что неправильно вывожу данные из функции `get_all_links` или неправильно их туда записываю:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_html(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    return r.text

def get_all_links(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

    tds = soup.find('table', id='currencies').find_all('td', class_='currency-name')

    links = []

    for td in tds:
        a = td.find('a').get('href')
        link = 'https://coinmarketcap.com' + a
        links.append(link)

        return links

def main():
    url = 'https://coinmarketcap.com'

    all_links = get_all_links( get_html(url) )

    for i in all_links:
        print(i)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

В выводе хочу получить список типа:

```
https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/
https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/ethereum/
https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/ripple/
```

и т.д.

На деле получаю только:

```
https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В функции `get_all_links` результат возвращается после первой итерации цикла. Нужно `return links` сдвинуть левее.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_html(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    return r.text

def get_all_links(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

    tds = soup.find('table', id='currencies').find_all('td', class_='currency-name')

    links = []

    for td in tds:
        a = td.find('a').get('href')
        link = 'https://coinmarketcap.com' + a
        links.append(link)

    return links

def main():
    url = 'https://coinmarketcap.com'

    all_links = get_all_links( get_html(url) )

    for i in all_links:
        print(i)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```